# XSLT Not Sorting Across Multiple Template Matches

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

XSLT 1.0

I am sorting text message output and am trying to have the sms and mms messages listed by date. 
The data is stuctured something like:

```
  <smses>
    <sms address="555555001" date="1517372455000" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello" name="John" />
    <sms address="555555001" date="1517372455004" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello" name="John" />
    <sms address="555555009" date="1517372458000" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello" name="Jane" />
    <sms address="555555009" date="1517372458001" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello" name="Jane" />
    <sms address="555555009" date="1517372458002" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello" name="Jane" />
    <sms address="555555001" date="1517372455005" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello" name="John" />
    <mms address="555555001" date="1517372455001" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello" name="John" />
    <mms address="555555001" date="1517372455002" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello" name="John" />
    <mms address="555555001" date="1517372455003" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello" name="John" />
   </smses>
```

I am generating a key that filters by "John" (@readable_date exists in actual data)

```
<xsl:key name="shortDate" match="sms[@name='John']|mms[@name='John']" use="@readable_date" />

<xsl:template match="/">    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/smses/sms[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('shortDate',@readable_date)[1])] | /smses/mms[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('shortDate',@readable_date)[1])]">
      <xsl:sort select="@date" data-type="number" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sms|mms">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('shortDate',@readable_date)">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" /><xsl:value-of select="@readable_date" /><xsl:value-of select="@message" />
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

No matter what I try, the mms messages always come after the sms messages instead of all the nodes being sorted by date.

Comment: Can you share the desired output based on the input XML? The shared XSLT code has some attributes viz. `@contact-name`, `@readable_date` that are not present in the input XML. Are these to be mapped to `@name` and `@date`?

Comment: @Aniket-V `@contact_name` should just be `@name`. The output will eventually be a list in a table and should just be a list of messages sorted by date.

Comment: Do you need the sorting to be done on `@name` and then `@date`?

Comment: No, I only need sorting by date. I assume the issue is applying multiple matches when using apply-templates. I don't know how to get both match sets to be sorted as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping elements by `@readable_date`, and sorting the groups; you are then outputting the contents of each group without further sorting (i.e., each group is output in document order).

But in your sample data, all the elements have the same @readable_date, so there is only one group, so sorting the groups achieves nothing. You need to sort the items within the group, that is the `xsl:for-each` instruction in the `match="sms|mms"` template rule needs an `xsl:sort` specification.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you would need a `<xsl:key>` to be defined if you are only looking for messages sent to `John`. You can apply a `<xsl:for-each>` filtered on `John` and then apply the sorting on `@date`. Below is the XSLT template.

```
<xsl:template match="smses">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[@name='John']">
        <xsl:sort select="@date" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
        <output>
            <xsl:value-of select="@message" />
        </output>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

In order to validate the output, I have made some changes to the `@message` value to know the difference. Below is the updated input XML.

```
<smses>
    <sms address="555555001" date="1517372455000" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello, This is SMS 1 for John." name="John" />
    <sms address="555555001" date="1517372455004" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello, This is SMS 2 for John." name="John" />
    <sms address="555555009" date="1517372458000" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello, This is SMS 1 for Jane." name="Jane" />
    <sms address="555555009" date="1517372458001" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello, This is SMS 2 for Jane." name="Jane" />
    <sms address="555555009" date="1517372458002" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello, This is SMS 3 for Jane." name="Jane" />
    <sms address="555555001" date="1517372455005" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello, This is SMS 3 for John." name="John" />
    <mms address="555555001" date="1517372455001" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello, This is MMS 1 for John." name="John" />
    <mms address="555555001" date="1517372455002" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello, This is MMS 2 for John." name="John" />
    <mms address="555555001" date="1517372455003" readable_date="Jan 30, 2018" message="Hello, This is MMS 3 for John." name="John" />
</smses>
```

Using the above XML, when the XSLT template is applied, the below sorted output is generated

```
<output>Hello, This is SMS 1 for John.</output>
<output>Hello, This is MMS 1 for John.</output>
<output>Hello, This is MMS 2 for John.</output>
<output>Hello, This is MMS 3 for John.</output>
<output>Hello, This is SMS 2 for John.</output>
<output>Hello, This is SMS 3 for John.</output>
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorting within the for-each is what did the trick. Your suggestion would work for the information provided, my actual program has a few additional details that needs the templates.